# `fixed` vs GCHandle.Alloc(obj, GCHandleType.Pinned)

Tags: c#

I tried to find out how pinned pointers defined with `fixed` keyword work. My idea was that internally `GCHandle.Alloc(object, GCHandleType.Pinned)` was used for that. But when I looked into the IL generated for the following C# code:

```
unsafe static void f1()
{
  var arr = new MyObject[10];
  fixed(MyObject * aptr = &arr[0])
  {
     Console.WriteLine(*aptr);
  }
}
```

I couldn't find any traces of `GCHandle`.

The only hint I saw that the pinned pointer was used in the method was the following IL declaration:

```
.locals init ([0] valuetype TestPointerPinning.MyObject[] arr,
              [1] valuetype TestPointerPinning.MyObject& pinned aptr)
```

So the pointer was declared as pinned, and that did not require any additional methods calls, to pin it.

My questions are

- Is there any difference between using pinned pointers in the declaration and pinning the pointer by using `GCHandle` class?
- Is there any way to declare a pinned pointer in C# without using `fixed` keyword? I need this to pin a bunch of pointers within a loop and there's no way I can do this using fixed keyword.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Well, sure there's a difference, you saw it.  The CLR supports more than one way to pin an object.  Only the GCHandleType.Pinned method is directly exposed to user code.  But there are others, like ["async pinned handles"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7555664/17034), a feature that keeps I/O buffers pinned while a driver performs an overlapped I/O operation.  And the one that the *fixed* keyword uses, it doesn't use an explicit handle or method call at all.  These extra ways were added to make unpinning the objects again as quick and reliable as possible, very important to GC health.

Fixed buffer pins are implemented by the jitter.  Which performs *two* important jobs when it translates MSIL to machine code, the highly visible one is the machine code itself, you can easily see it with the debugger.  But it also generates a data structure used by the garbage collector, completely invisible in the debugger.  Required by the GC to reliably find object references back that are stored in the stack frame or a CPU register.  More about that data structure in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17131389/17034).

The jitter uses the [pinned] attribute on the variable declaration in the metadata to set a bit in that data structure, indicating that the object that's referenced by the variable is temporarily pinned.  The GC sees this and knows to not move the object.  Very efficient because it doesn't require an explicit method call to allocate the handle and doesn't require any storage.

But no, these tricks are not available otherwise to C# code, you really *do* need to use the *fixed* keyword in your code.  Or GCHandle.Alloc().  If you are finding yourself getting lost in the pins then high odds that you ought to be considering pinvoke or C++/CLI so you can easily call native code.  The temporary pins that the pinvoke marshaller uses to keep objects stable while the native code is running are another example of automatic pinning that doesn't require explicit code.

Comment: So, does the `fixed` has better performance than `GCHandle.Alloc(xxx, GCHandleType.Pinned)`?